# Boostrap icons is not working in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5, .net-7.0

I am trying to use bootstrap icons with ASP.NET Core 7 MVC and Bootstrap 5

I am using this cdn in `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

I got this error in browser console:

> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Does anyone know what the issue is, and can you help me with this?

Comment: Must be a problem to your Internet. I can access that file just fine.

Comment: This is a networking issue that can't be fixed in code. If access to that CDN is blocked, try a different one. If you can't connect outside the company's intranet at all, you'll have to use a local copy instead of a CDN